# Is there a way to open a Excel file from within PowerBI?

Tags: excel, powerbi

See the question in the title.

The background here is that I would like to open the Excel as a form where the user can enter data that will then be used to change the visualisations in the dashboard.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: This looks very much like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Take a look how you can [write-back](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/data/power-bi-write-back-power-apps) from Power BI.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. Thinking about it, you might be rigth about the XY issue, however I don't think that the built-in write back functionalities via Power App can provide what I'm after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while I was made aware that opening a spreadsheet from within PBI might not be an ideal process, here is a solution to my question that I found after a bit of trying:

Assuming you can store an Excel file (that is consumed by your report) on some server (e.g. Sharepoint), you can add a button to your PBI dashboard and simply link it to the file. Clicking the button then opens the file and lets you do changes. A refresh will then update whatever visuals are using the file.